# Relativistic oscillator vs. non relativistic oscillator

Tags: special-relativity, harmonic-oscillator

Consider a particle of mass $m$ that is constrained to move under the potential $U=k|x|$.
In the case where the particle's motion is non-relativistic, the Lagrangian for the motion is $L=T-V=\frac{m}{2} \dot x ^2 -k|x|$
and similarly the energy is $H=\frac{m}{2} \dot x ^2 +k|x|=const.$

Now, in the case where the particle's motion is rather relativistic and it's kinetic energy is given by $E_k=pc$, (a very small mass), the energy of the system becomes $H=c |p|+k|x|=const.$

Obviously, the particle's velocity goes to zero when it reaches the limits of the motion.

So, my relativistic assumption breaks down at those points.
What are the physical conditions, then, for which my equation for the energy is correct?

Comment: I disagree with your relativistic Hamiltonian.

Comment: Also, I'd not say that this is an oscillator, given that $V=\frac12kx^2$ for the HO (whereas the *force* would be $F=-kx$).

Comment: @KyleKanos: That's the $V$ I want to to consider the case with.

Comment: Then you don't have a harmonic oscillator, more like a gravitational potential.

Comment: Well that's correct. I will edit the original question.

Comment: The equations $L=T-V,\,H=T+V$ imply $H+L=2T$. The correct expression in general is $\dot{x}\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{x}}$. I advise you to compute that expression, then compare it with the kinetic energy. Expressing everything in terms of rapidity will make the task easier.